# Let$\ x$ be a real number between$\ 0$ and$\ 1$. Is it possible to write$\ e^{x}$ as a function of$\ \Gamma \left(x+1\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, proof-writing, exponential-function, gamma-function

In particular, I'm looking for a relation between$\ e^x$ and$\ \frac{1}{ \Gamma \left(x+1\right) }$, which would be of help for a proof.

Comment: What do you mean by $x!$ for a number between $0$ and $1$? Is it the Gamma function?

Comment: @A.Breust Yes. Should I edit it?

Comment: @A.Breust I was thinking too much of how I was writing it in a software, in order to do it faster.

Comment: If you mean the Gamma function, $\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty  x^{t-1} e^{-x}\,dx$

Comment: I have edited the question, yes, I'm referring to the Gamma function.

@gerardpc I see. And there aren't "easier" forms, I guess?

Comment: There are a lot of formulas regarding the Gamma function. You can check the wikipedia's article, maybe you find something you can use.

Comment: Alright, I shall do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is the relation: $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+z)}=e^{y(z)},$$ where $$y(z)=\gamma z-\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k \zeta(k)z^k}{k},$$ and $\gamma$ is Euler's gamma constant and $\zeta(x)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, let $y=e^x$ and $z=1/\Gamma(x+1)$, then $$y=\exp(\Gamma^{-1}(1/z)-1),$$ provided $x$ is restricted to some domain where $x\mapsto\Gamma(x+1)$ is injective with inverse $\Gamma^{-1}$, say $$x\geqslant0.47.$$

Comment: You say I should specify that I'm looking for non-trivial possibilities?